# SQL Returning Duplicate Rows but with column value flipped when referencing the same table twice

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to join a table with itself using a common ID to find instances where a certain column are not equal. My problem is that my script returns almost duplicate rows, but the values in the returned columns are swapped (and so a distinct will not work).

An example would be:

```
Select distinct t1.ID, t1.Value V1, t2.Value V2
from t1, t2
where t1.ID = t2.ID 
and t1.Value <> t2.Value
```

This returns:

```
ID  V1  V2
1   A   B
2   B   A
```

When I'd like it to just return the single row:

```
ID  V1  V2
1   A   B
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest?

```
Select t1.ID, t1.Value as V1, t2.Value as V2
from t1 join
     t2
     on t1.ID = t2.ID and
        t1.Value < t2.Value;
```

Note that the change is `<` rather than `<>`.

Comment: This works perfectly, I can't believe I didn't think of that!

Answer (score 0):

You could use `LEAST/GREATEST` functions:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.ID,
     LEAST(t1.Value , t2.Value)   AS V1,
     GREATEST(t1.Value, t2.Value) AS V2
FROM t1
JOIN t2
  ON t1.ID = t2.ID 
WHERE t1.Value <> t2.Value;
```

**[DBFiddle Demo](http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=1f691ce3e994583b3473ee7177e52188)**